# How to use a .patch file?

Tags: 14.04, patch

I did the instructions found in [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1624005). During the process it seems that it is looking for another file as it displays something in my terminal like this:

```
> patch -p1 < HID-core-fix-computation-of-the-report-size.patch

> can't find file to patch at input line 5
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
> --------------------------
|diff --git a/drivers/hid/hid-core.c b/drivers/hid/hid-core.c
|index 963a8da..e0f6753 100644
|--- a/drivers/hid/hid-core.c
|+++ b/drivers/hid/hid-core.c
--------------------------
> File to patch:
```

What do I enter?
The file that I'm patching is a patch that is said to fix the [touchpad not being recognize](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/4096321/). It is the HID patch that can be found at the download link in that site.

Answer (score 1):

This is a kernel patch, it is used to make modifications to the kernel source code. After applying it, you would need to [recompile the kernel](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile) (from the modified source code), which is not a trivial operation and which you probably don't want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with fkraiem that you probably do not want to apply that patch yourself.

The [mail thread](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/4096321/) ends saying that the fix will be in kernel version 3.15.
The latest standard package version available for trusty is 3.13 currently.

The current version for the next Ubuntu release, Utopic, is [3.16](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=linux-generic). Maybe you can just wait for Utopic, release planed for [October 23rd](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UtopicUnicorn/ReleaseSchedule)?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

I updated my BIOS version and it made my touchpad work but after several minutes the laptop froze. What I did was to close the lid to make the laptop hibernate then open it again. It's not frozen anymore, however, the touchpad is not working anymore. It seems that ubuntu has issues with asus bios.
This is really not an answer to the original question. However, this is an alternative for someone with the same problem (touchpad not working). But this solution (updating bios) is VERY RISKY. Use this solution to your own risk.